# How do we run multiple tests for the same controller in a MicronautTest class?

Tags: junit5, micronaut

There is an EmployeeController with two endpoints. One is **/employee/{employeeid}/department** and **/employee/{employeeid}/salary**. I have written the test cases in micronaut for both endpoints. They both run successfully if run individually. 
 However, when run together, facing `io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.HttpClientResponseException: Not Found`. Using only one HttpClient to run both the tests.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to do it. See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/nacharymntests.

```
package nacharymntests;

import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;

@Controller("/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Get("/hello/{name}")
    public String hello(String name) {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }

    @Get("/goodbye/{name}")
    public String goodbye(String name) {
        return "Goodbye " + name;
    }
}
```

Test 1:

```
package nacharymntests

import io.micronaut.context.ApplicationContext
import io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClient
import io.micronaut.runtime.server.EmbeddedServer
import spock.lang.AutoCleanup
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification

class LowLevelClientSpec extends Specification {

    @Shared
    @AutoCleanup
    EmbeddedServer embeddedServer = ApplicationContext.run(EmbeddedServer)

    @Shared
    @AutoCleanup
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.create(embeddedServer.URL)

    void "test hello"() {
        expect:
        client.toBlocking().retrieve("/employee/hello/Jeff") == 'Hello Jeff'
    }

    void "test goodbye"() {
        expect:
        client.toBlocking().retrieve("/employee/goodbye/Jeff") == 'Goodbye Jeff'
    }
}
```

Test 2:

```
package nacharymntests

import io.micronaut.context.ApplicationContext
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get
import io.micronaut.http.client.annotation.Client
import io.micronaut.runtime.server.EmbeddedServer
import spock.lang.AutoCleanup
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification

class DeclarativeClientSpec extends Specification {

    @Shared
    @AutoCleanup
    EmbeddedServer embeddedServer = ApplicationContext.run(EmbeddedServer)

    @Shared
    AnotherEmployeeClient client = embeddedServer.applicationContext.getBean(AnotherEmployeeClient)

    void "test hello"() {
        expect:
        client.hello('Jeff') == 'Hello Jeff'
    }

    void "test goodbye"() {
        expect:
        client.goodbye('Jeff') == 'Goodbye Jeff'
    }
}

@Client(value = '/', path = '/employee')
interface AnotherEmployeeClient {

    @Get('/hello/{name}')
    String hello(String name)

    @Get('/goodbye/{name}')
    String goodbye(String name)
}
```

Test 3:

```
package nacharymntests

import io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClient
import io.micronaut.http.client.annotation.Client
import io.micronaut.test.annotation.MicronautTest
import spock.lang.AutoCleanup
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification

import javax.inject.Inject

@MicronautTest
class LowLevelClientWithTestFrameworkSpec extends Specification {

    @AutoCleanup
    @Shared
    @Inject
    @Client("/")
    HttpClient client

    void "test hello"() {
        expect:
        client.toBlocking().retrieve("/employee/hello/Jeff") == 'Hello Jeff'
    }

    void "test goodbye"() {
        expect:
        client.toBlocking().retrieve("/employee/goodbye/Jeff") == 'Goodbye Jeff'
    }
}
```

Test 4:

```
package nacharymntests

import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get
import io.micronaut.http.client.annotation.Client
import io.micronaut.test.annotation.MicronautTest
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification

import javax.inject.Inject

@MicronautTest
class DeclarativeClientWithTestFrameworkSpec extends Specification {

    @Shared
    @Inject
    EmployeeClient client

    void "test hello"() {
        expect:
        client.hello('Jeff') == 'Hello Jeff'
    }

    void "test goodbye"() {
        expect:
        client.goodbye('Jeff') == 'Goodbye Jeff'
    }
}

@Client(value = '/', path = '/employee')
interface EmployeeClient {

    @Get('/hello/{name}')
    String hello(String name)

    @Get('/goodbye/{name}')
    String goodbye(String name)
}
```

Comment: You didn't indicate which test framework you are using.  The above examples all use Spock but basically the same thing can be done with JUnit.

Comment: I see now that you used the tag `junit5` on the question, which I didn't notice initially.  The commit at https://github.com/jeffbrown/nacharymntests/commit/600a186d66b1e39636cbc5b85391b81c98497f7c on the `use-junit` branch shows some JUnit tests which pass.  I hope that helps.

Comment: Yes I was able to use the HttpClient for all the tests by mocking it before they were run using `client = HttpClient.create(server.getURL());`. In my case, I was blocking the client using `client.toBlocking()` inside every test which is why it worked only for one test and not for others. Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me.  As you see, `LowLevelClientWithTestFrameworkSpec` is using `toBlocking()` inside each test and that is fine.  `toBlocking()` should not be a problem.

Comment: Previously, I was just using `@Inject@Client("/")RxHttpClient client;` to inject an instance of the client as shown in the documentation. This worked only if I had one test. I tried it with two tests and only one test passed while the other failed giving a `io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.HttpClientResponseException: Not Found` exception since that client instance was already in use (or blocked) by a test method and was unavailable for use by the other test method.

Comment: The test at https://github.com/jeffbrown/nacharymntests/blob/4e55967c1edf575d62e5a25ded34b6df6c183e66/src/test/java/nacharymntests/LowLevelClientWithTestFrameworkTest.java works (and also works if you change `HttpClient` to `RxHttpClient` of course).

Comment: Have you tried the above test with any GET/POST/PUT mappings? If injecting a client instance like how I tried previously, works with these different mappings then let me know since I tried it out again and it still gives this exception but it works great when I give `client = HttpClient.create(server.getURL());` before every test is run. So my problem's solved but it still doesn't work with `@Inject@Client("/")RxHttpClient client;` for which I have no clue why.

Comment: I am happy to look at a sample project which demonstrates the issue you are describing.